# bash picking arguments

Tags: bash

I want to write a function for when I have something like the following

```
echo 1 2 3|pick
```

Pick will then take the arguments and I will do something with them.

How do I do this?

Comment: Should `pick` try to get hold of the arguments to `echo`? (Even if `echo` is replaced by some other command?)

Comment: yes I think that should only take args for echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pick() {
  read -r arg1 arg2 remainder
  echo first arg is $arg1
  echo The remaining args are $remainder
}
```

--EDIT  (response to question in comment)

One way to loop through the arguments:

```
pick() {
  read args;
  set $args;
  while test $# -ne 0; do
    echo $1
    shift
  done
}
```

On each iteration of the loop, $1 refers to an argument.

Comment: How to read all arguments in while cuz i can have 10 arguments or more?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs)?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the OP wants the same thing I do: you feed it a string, and if the string containes multiple {words,lines}, it presents you a menu, and you pick one, and it returns the one you pick on stdout.

If there's only one item, it just returns it.

This is useful for--to use my particular use-case--a log file viewer script: you give it a substring of a filename, and it greps through `find /var/log -name \*$arg\* -print` to see what it can find.  If it gets a unique hit, it hands it back to your script, which runs less against it.  If it gets more than one hit, it shows you a menu, and lets you pick one.

ISTR that KSH has a builtin for this, but that I wasn't all that impressed with it; I don't recall if bash has one.

I am here because I was searching to see if someone had already written it before writing it myself.  :-)

UPDATE: Nope; I wrote it myself:

Here's some example code:

/usr/local/bin/msg:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

[ $UID = 0 ] || exec sudo su root -c "$0 $*"

FILE=/var/log/messages

[ $# -eq 1 ] &&
   FILE=`find /var/log/ -name \*$1\* -print |
   egrep -v '2011|.[0-9]$' |
   pick`

echo "$FILE"
less +F $FILE
```

Since I'm piping the name to less +F I want to grep out archived log files; this is for interactive log viewing.

/usr/local/bin/pick:

```
# Present the user a bash Select menu, and let them pick
# Try to be smart about multi-line responses

# must take input on stdin if it might be multiline

# get multiline input from stdin
while read LINE </dev/stdin
do
        CHOICES+=( $LINE )
done

# add on anything specified as arguments
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
        CHOICES+=( $1 )
        shift
done


# if only one thing to pick, just pick it
if [ ${#CHOICES[*]} -eq 1 ]
then
        echo $CHOICES
        exit
fi


# eval set $CHOICES
select CHOSEN in ${CHOICES[@]}
do
        echo $CHOSEN
        exit
done </dev/tty
```

Comment: Yeah, apparently it's 'select':

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-script-using-select-to-show-multi-word-options-like-option-1-o-317671/